# ¿Como cambiar superindices a POW(n,n) con Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

estoy intentando reemplazar la notación de (n)^(m) por POWER(n,m) debido a que quiero usar SQL para procesar la fórmula. Pero no he encontrado la manera de hacerlo por regex.

Tengo este ejemplo:

```
(((2+2))^((1)))+((41)^(((2)^((2)))))
```

Mi objetivo es llegar a:

```
(POWER(((2+2)),((1))))+(POWER(41,(POWER(2,2))))
```

Intenté con algo como esto:

```
x=x.replace(/([\(])+(.*)+([\)])+(\^)+(\()+(.*)+(\))/gi, "(POWER(($2$3,$5$6");
```

Pero aún soy muy novato en el uso de Regex. ¿Creen que sea posible lo que busco?

No me limito a regex, si a alguién se le ocurre otra forma de resolverlo es agradecería.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para una solución pura con expresiones regulares, sólo se puede usando recursividad (`(?R)` o `(?1)`). Lamentablemente la librería de regex estándar de JavaScript no lo permite. En otro lenguaje sería más sencillo.

Así que vamos a implementar un poco de parseo con regex y otro tanto de recursividad desde el código nativo.

```js
function exp_pow(str) {
  const regex = /^([^^]*?)([^()^ ][^()^]*)?\^([^()^]*[^()^ ])?(.+)?/g;
  let m, izq, paren, base, exp, der;

  while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
      izq = '';
      if (m[2]) { //si tiene una base sin paréntesis
        izq = m[1];
        base = m[2];
      } else {
        try {
          //obtener la base con paréntesis
          paren = XRegExp.matchRecursive(m[1], '\\(', '\\)', 'g', {
            valueNames: ['izq', null, 'base', null]
          });
        } catch(err) { //si no está balanceado
          //sacar paréntesis exteriores y 
          //probar de cero con interior
          //también con lo que quede a la derecha
          paren = XRegExp.matchRecursive(str, '\\(', '\\)', 'g', {
                      valueNames: ['izq', null, 'paren', null]
          });
          return paren.reduce(
            (acc, curr) => {
              if (curr.name=='paren')
                return acc + '(' + exp_pow(curr.value) + ')';
              return acc + curr.value;
            },
            ''
          ) + str.substr(paren[paren.length - 1].end + 1);
        }
        
        //se encontró la base con paréntesis
        if (paren.length == 1) {
          base = paren[0].value;
        } else {
          izq = paren[0].value;
          base = paren[1].value;
        }
      }
      
      //buscar el exponente
      if (m[3]) { //no tiene paréntesis
        exp = m[3];
        der = m[4];
      } else { //obtener paréntesis exteriores
        paren = XRegExp.matchRecursive(m[4], '\\(', '\\)', '', {
          valueNames: [null, null, 'exp', null]
        });
        exp = paren[0].value;
        der = m[4].substr(paren[0].end + 1);
      }
      
      //resultado con cada una de las partes
      str = izq+'POWER('+base+','+exp+')'+der;
      //resetear el regex para que vuelva a ir contra todo el string
      regex.lastIndex = 0;
  }
  return str;
}



//PRUEBA
console.log(
  exp_pow('(((2+2))^((1)))+((41)^(((2)^((2)))))')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xregexp/xregexp-all.js"></script>
```

Básicamente usé este regex para obtener el primer `^` dividiendo el string en 4 grupos:

```
/^([^^]*?)([^()^ ][^()^]*)?\^([^()^]*[^()^ ])?(.+)?/g
```

1. `([^^]*?)` el contenido de la izquierda con paréntesis
2. `([^()^ ][^()^]*)?` si a la izquierda hay contenido sin paréntesis, sino devuelve vacío
3. `([^()^]*[^()^ ])?` si a la derecha hay contenido sin paréntesis, sino devuelve vacío
4. `(.+)?` el resto de todo lo que queda a la derecha

En `base^exponente`, la base está formada por el grupo 2, pero si devolvió vacío, tiene paréntesis y está en el grupo 1. El exponente está en el grupo 3, pero si devolvió vacío, tiene paréntesis y está en el grupo 4.

Cuando base o exponente tienen paréntesis, hay que verificar que estén balanceados. Para verificar paréntesis balanceados usamos [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/), una librería externa que implementa [matchRecursive()](http://xregexp.com/api/#matchRecursive), para devolver el contenido de los 1ros paréntesis externos balanceados.

Si toma como base a algo como `((2)` significa que no está balanceado, por lo que busco los paréntesis exteriores, separo y vuelvo a correr recursivamente sólo la parte interna de los paréntesis.

Cada vez que ocurre un reemplazo, se vuelve a correr todo el código contra todo el string. Esto se hace con `regex.lastIndex = 0;`, para que el regex se vuelva a intentar desde la posición 0.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma de cambiar el operador de potencia por la función POWER es hacer un
plugin de [Babel](https://babeljs.io).

Babel es un conjunto de librerias que puede procesar código de JavaScript
para generar un AST (Abstract Syntax Tree), transformarlo y producir código.

Para usarlo se debe instalar en una carpeta nueva usando npm con el siguiente comando:

```
npm install --save @babel/core
```

Luego, puedes guardar el siguiente ejemplo en un archivo index.js y ejecutarlo
con `node index.js`.

```
const babel = require("@babel/core");
const { types: t, transform: transform } = babel;

const power = {
    visitor: {
        BinaryExpression(path) {
            if (path.node.operator === "**") {
                const callee = t.identifier("POWER");
                const args = [path.node.left, path.node.right];

                path.replaceWith(t.callExpression(callee, args));
            }
        }
    }
};

const code = "(((2+2^3))^((1)))+((41)^(((2)^((2)))))";

transform(code.replace(/\^/g, "**"), {plugins: [power]}, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result.code);
});
```

Antes de pasarle el código a babel.transform se remplazan los `^` (que en JS es el operador
XOR) por el operador de potencia en JS `**`, ya que tienen distinta precedencia y sino daría
resultados erroneos.

Lo que hace es recorrer cada nodo en el AST, y si es de tipo BinaryExpression
con `**` de operador, lo remplaza por un nodo de tipo CallExpression (un
llamado a función) con POWER como nombre de la función y, la parte izquierda y
derecha del operador `**` como argumentos.

El resultado:

```
POWER(2 + POWER(2, 3), 1) + POWER(41, POWER(2, 2));
```